# positioning my button near the text box for an html document

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i need help in getting my seach button near my text box it seems to come below the text box
program:

```
<div class="search-full text-right">
    <a class="pull-right search-close"><i class=" fa fa-times-circle"></i></a>
    <div class="searchInputBox pull-right">
        <input type="search"
               data-searchurl="search?="
               name="q"
               placeholder="start typing and hit enter to search"
               class="search-input">
        <button class="btn-nobg search-btn" type="submit">
            <i class="fa fa-search"> </i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the css as well to understand your problem

Comment: <div class="search-box pull-right hidden-lg hidden-md hidden-sm">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-nobg" type="button"> <i class="fa fa-search"> </i> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    </div>

Comment: Use the proper html for that, that twitter-bootstrap provides. Here's the example > http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: You realize that this is all we can see from your code? http://jsbin.com/jozahuqihoxo/2/edit

Answer (score 2):

As per Bootstrap standard, using an input-group is the best bet.

See: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

[Bootply Example using some of your code](http://www.bootply.com/jy01VfSIoT)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="input-group">
   <input type="search"
           data-searchurl="search?="
           name="q"
           placeholder="start typing and hit enter to search"
           class="search-input form-control">
   <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn search-btn" type="submit">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"> </i>
    </button>
   </span>
  </div><!-- /input-group -->
 </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
</div>
```

EDIT: I've also created a Bootply fork with the 'clear' button for you, though it's slightly hacked. See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xI9UcfpG2l)